# Zend Select() add cases after declaration?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm learning Zend Framework and I'm working through a Database inconvenience.

Using php you could do some string manipulation like this

```
$sqlstatement = "select id,name from TABLE where ID='$id'";

if ($admin == true) {
$sqlstatement .= " and admin = 'Yes'";  
}
```

Is there a way to do this with Zend? currently I am doing something like this.

```
if ($admin == true){

   $sqlstatement = $this->select()
                        ->from($this->_name,array('id','name'))
                        ->where("ID='$id'")
                        ->where("admin = 'Yes'");

}else{

   $sqlstatement = $this->select()
                        ->from($this->_name,array('id','name'))
                        ->where("ID='$id'");
}
```

Ideally I would like to do something like...

```
   $sqlstatement = $this->select()
                        ->from($this->_name,array('id','name'))
                        ->where("ID='$id'");
if ($admin == true){
       $sqlstatement .= $this->select()
                             ->where("admin = 'Yes'");
}
```

I have a Model creating the queries and returning them to my view. So the $this->select() is actually happening in my model class function and returning the Zend_Db_Table_Row Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `select()` returns the select object which you can call methods on as many times as you wish, so:

```
$sqlstatement = $this->select()
                     ->from($this->_name,array('id','name'))
                     ->where("ID='$id'");
if ($admin == true){
       $sqlstatement->where("admin = 'Yes'");
}
```

also you should really use parameterised queries to avoid SQL injection, so I would rewrite this code as:

```
$sqlstatement = $this->select()
                     ->from($this->_name, array('id','name'))
                     ->where('ID= ?', $id);
if ($admin){
       $sqlstatement->where('admin = ?', 'Yes');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i see what i was doing with the .= it was creating a new separate select and adding it to the end so i was going a "where id='$id' where admin = 'yes';". Also thanks i didn't realize that  would sanitize the code saves a step. Thanks again!!